# C# Memory layout issue

Tags: c#

I would like some enlightenment on some memory layout issue am having and struggling to make sense of it.
This is my program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ManagementSysInfo
{
    class Program
    {
        public enum ACTION_TYPE :uint
        {
            NONE,  // 0
            RESTART, // 1.
            ABORT, // 2.
            WAIT //3
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct ACTIONS
        {
            public ACTION_TYPE type;
            public int delay;

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numAction = 3;

            ACTIONS action1 = new ACTIONS()
            {
                type = ACTION_TYPE.RESTART,
                delay = 10000
            };

            ACTIONS action2, action3;
            action2 = action3 = action1;
            ACTIONS[] sc_act_array = new[] { action1, action2, action3 };

            int[] actionsArray = new int[numAction * 2];
            int index = -1;
            foreach (ACTIONS act in sc_act_array)
            {
                actionsArray[++index] = (int)act.type;
                actionsArray[++index] = (int)act.delay;
            }

            int buffsize = Marshal.SizeOf(actionsArray[0]) * actionsArray.Length ;
            IntPtr actions_ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffsize);

            Marshal.Copy(actionsArray, 0, actions_ptr, sc_act_array.Length);

            int i =Marshal.SizeOf(actions_ptr);

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(actions_ptr);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok what i am trying to acheive here is marshal an array of structure to unmanaged memory. But after some reading here and there people seems to say that the marshal class in the interop service doesn't provide a clean way to marshal array of structures. And it's better sometimes if doable( I guess for not complex struct ) to express it as an array of primitive.
Hence my **actionsArray** variable holds the packed content of the struct array **sc_act_array**. And my **actions_ptr** will hold a reference to the content of **actionsArray** in the unmanaged memory. From my understding if everything goes right, I can read the information marshalled by using the pointer and adding some offset to it. 
Since every element in the array occipies a 4 bytes memory space ( correct me if am wrong) I had that mapping in my head thinking that's how the data in the unmanaged memory should map the one marshalled from managed memory :

> (actions_ptr, 0) = actionsArray[0] = 1
>
> (actions_ptr, 4) = actionsArray[1] = 10000
>
> (actions_ptr, 8) = actionsArray[2] = 1
>
> (actions_ptr, 12) = actionsArray[3] = 10000
>
> (actions_ptr, 16) = actionsArray[4] = 1
>
> (actions_ptr, 20) = actionsArray[5] = 10000

When you run the program everything goes well, no exception. But when i debbug and inspect the content by offsetting the pointer by a value of 4 byte i get something wierd, the following comes from my Immediate window :

> Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 0) 
>   1
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 4) 
>   10000
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 8) 
>   1
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 12) 
>   1
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 16) 
>   192
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 20)
>
> Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 24) 
>   461628657
>   Marshal.ReadInt32(actions_ptr, 28)
>   -2147483640

I am struggling to understand why the memory is not layed out as I expected. Am i missing something here?
I thought that it might be related to the fact that the CPU likes to process data in specifics chunk (ie: 8 bytes) and somehow it's adding some padding inbetween. Or maybe it's just the fact that Marshal.copy copies the data to unmanaged memory in a non sequential way.

Can anybody shed some light please.

Thanks

Comment: *marshal class in the interop service doesn't provide a clean way to marshal array of structures* Do you have references to this?

Comment: I've seen it in a couple of blogs. This is the last one i can remember: look at Issue1. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6164/A-ServiceInstaller-Extension-That-Enables-Recovery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marshaling of arrays of simple structs from C# to C/C++ works perfectly well. The problem is in the opposite direction: you can't create an array C/C++ side and marshal it to C#, because the CLR can't know the size of the array.

Test code:

C#

```
public enum ACTION_TYPE : uint
{
    NONE,  // 0
    RESTART, // 1.
    ABORT, // 2.
    WAIT //3
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ACTIONS
{
    public ACTION_TYPE type;
    public int delay;

}

[DllImport("NativeLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void testarray(ACTIONS[] actions, int len);

var actions = new[] 
{
    new ACTIONS { type = ACTION_TYPE.RESTART, delay = 11 },
    new ACTIONS { type = ACTION_TYPE.ABORT, delay = 22 },
    new ACTIONS { type = ACTION_TYPE.WAIT, delay = 33 },
};

testarray(actions, actions.Length);
```

C++

```
enum ACTION_TYPE : unsigned int
{
    NONE,  // 0
    RESTART, // 1.
    ABORT, // 2.
    WAIT //3
};

struct ACTIONS
{
    ACTION_TYPE type;
    int delay;
};

__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall testarray(ACTIONS* actions, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%u %d\n", actions[i].type, actions[i].delay);
    }
}
```

**and for your error**

```
Marshal.Copy(actionsArray, 0, actions_ptr, actionsArray.Length);
```

This is the correct `Marshal.Copy`. You were copying too few bytes.

Comment: Ha ok good to know the issue about marshaling struct array only applies when going from C# to c/c++. Thanks for the info. But here am more interested in understanding how the memory layout is worked out by the run-time environment if you see what i mean. And why my data are not where they are supposed to be.

Comment: @user3485103 See the bold section in the end. You were copying too few bytes.

Comment: @user3485103 *the issue about marshaling struct array only applies when going from C# to c/c++.* No, it is the opposite. The problem only occurs if you want C/C++ to allocate memory and pass it to C#. You can create an array in C#, pass it to C++, modify its values (**not its size, its values**) in C/C++ and read the modified values in C# without any problem. The only problem is if the C/C++ has to create an array and pass it to C#.

Comment: sorry i didn't notice the part in bold. And regarding marshaling struct array I got it. I typed it wrong on the comment even though i thought it right in my head lol (brain magic). Thanks for your help. So what do you think i should do to avoid copying a few bytes? Cause i did the math (unless it's wrong) the memory space allocated in the unmanaged memory is 24 bytes which matches the size of the array.

Comment: @user3485103 Look at my line... it is different from yours! **This is the correct Marshal.Copy. You were copying too few bytes.**

Comment: Ho god thanks mate you know what I've never notice I was passing the length of the struct array rather the int[]. all the time i've been reading it I was seeing actionsArray lol. ( just in case anybody wonder I haven't smoked anything lol).  Thanks very much Xanatos